# Touch start Event Handle on Windows Phone c#

Tags: c#, xaml, windows-phone-8, touch, gestures

I've made some researches and I found that on [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/hh202911(v=vs.105).aspx#UX_Interactions_Tap)

It says that:

Tap

There are two behaviors associated with a tap gesture:

1. Finger down provides touch indication
2. Finger up executes the action

I want to handle only the first behavior (On finger Down), but I didn't find anything.
How can I handle this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [`ManipulationStarted`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.uielement.manipulationstarted%28v=vs.95%29.aspx) event to handle touch start event. Basically, this event occurs when user begins a manipulation on the `UIElement` doesn't matter what the gesture is :

```
private void MyControl_ManipulationStarted(object sender, 
                            System.Windows.Input.ManipulationStartedEventArgs e)
{

}
```

Answer (score 1):

Why don't you try using the `MouseLeave` and `MouseEnter` events to your control.

So i guess in your case you could use the `MouseEnter` event.

[MSDN reference](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.uielement.mouseleave(v=vs.110).aspx)